# Explanation of the chcon command

Tags: command-line, chcon

Could somebody explain this command:

```
chcon -R --reference=/var/www/html/ /var/www/html/install
```

I have read the explanation given in the book; but, I am unable to understand it clearly. Please use simple terminology while explaining the command.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are in this case:

```
chcon -R --reference=RFILE FILE
```

where:

- `chcon` - change file security context; you can check any security context of a file with `ls -Z`.
- `-R` - operate on files and directories recursively.
- `--reference=RFILE` - use  RFILE's  security  context rather than specifying a CONTEXT value.

So, the above command change recursively the security context of each file from `/var/www/html/install` to those from `/var/www/html`.

Type `info coreutils 'chcon invocation'` in terminal and  you will have access to the complete manual.

[This manual](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux) can helps you to understand everything about Security-Enhanced Linux (SELinux).

Comment: Thank you for your answer , did you mean that security context of /var/www/html will be applied to all the files that are placing in /var/www/html/install directory.

Comment: @Jai That's correct

Comment: could you please explain more about "security context ". Thank you.

Comment: I think this page can helps you http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux to understand SELinux and its "security context"

Comment: @Jai  you can check any security context of a file with `ls -Z`

Comment: chcon is a temporary solution. You want to either use restorecon, enable a Boolean, or debug selinux, depending on the context or avc denials.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Nothing more than true, but the OP asked for an explanation about what does `chcon` command. When I ask about `dir` command, I don't expect an answer which will recommend me `ls` command.

Comment: True, but ... When they ask about a rm command that will potentially cause problems, we usually caution them. The "problem" with chcon is that it may seemingly solve a problem, but  as soon as the file system needs to be relabeled, all sorts of problems spring up.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using **selinux**, I suggest you read the Fedora documentation.

See :

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SELinux_FAQ

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/

That second link is for Fedora 13, but, IMO, remains the most up to date document on selinux.

An oversimplification of selinux is to consider it an extension of file permissions ( above and beyond owner:group:other). So every file has a context. If a file is used by a http server, then there is no reason a ftp server should be accessing it. You can allow a ftp server to access the files by enabling a Boolean.

The problem you will have, chcon does not survive a relabel or restorecon.

> 5.7.1. Temporary Changes: `chcon`
>   The chcon command changes the SELinux context for files. However, changes made with the chcon command do not survive a file system relabel, or the execution of the /sbin/restorecon command. SELinux policy controls whether users are able to modify the SELinux context for any given file. When using chcon, users provide all or part of the SELinux context to change. An incorrect file type is a common cause of SELinux denying access.

chcon is intended for temporary changes.

See https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/12/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files.html.

You almost certainly will want to use restorecon

```
sudo /sbin/restorecon -R -v /var/www/
```

If that fails, post the avc denials and provide more information on what you are wanting to do. Most likely there would be a Boolean that you would need to configure.

See https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Troubleshooting-Fixing_Problems.html

Comment: But It guided to do like that, I am following RHCE guide.